# Fancybox resize Jquery

Tags: jquery, fancybox-2

How do i resize the pop based on the content of the jsp ?

I am using the following

```
      $j.fancybox({
                'autoSize': true, 
                'transitionIn': 'fade', 
                'transitionOut': 'fade', 
                'href': 'test.jsp' 
                'autoDimensions'    : true,
                'type': 'iframe'

            });
```